# Как правильно организовать переходы к отдельным View

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Я создал несколько интерфейсов в .xib как сделать так чтобы при переходе с вьюшки на сториборде открывался созданный мною .xib? Простите за глупый вопрос но только еще учусь.

Answer (score 1):

Смешивать storyboard и xib - плохая практика, которая непременно приведёт к трудностям в будущем при развитии и поддержке приложения. Стоит выбрать что-нибудь одно.

Если же всё же необходимо сделать так, как вы описываете, наиболее простой способ - это связать UIControl, инициирующий переход, с неким IBAction (в случае простой кнопки это делается простым перетаскиванием с удерживанием Ctrl или правой кнопкой мыши от кнопки к пустому месту в имплементации того ViewController, где лежит кнопка). Уже в самом теле IBAction-метода вы создаёте следующий ViewController через обычный alloc-init (если имя xib совпадает с именем класса ViewController'a) и показываете его через `[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES]`.